# Finite number of jumps in metric for space with finite number of components

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, metric-geometry

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with at most countably-infite many discontinuities and fix $x \in X$.  For every $r \geq 0$, define the sets $A(r)$ by
$$
A(r)\triangleq \{y \in X : d(x,y)=r\},
$$ 
and define the function
$$
\begin{aligned}
g:[0,\infty)\rightarrow [0,\infty)\\
g(r)\triangleq \begin{cases}
1 : & A(r)\neq \emptyset\\
0 :&A(r)= \emptyset\\
\end{cases}.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Edit**
How can I prove that the number of discontinuities of $g$ is bounded above by the number of components of $(X,d)$.

**Note:**
The original question asked for equality, but @AIM_BLB showed that is false.

Comment: Take countably many points on the circumference of a circle and let $x$ be the centroid in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Making this countable set into a metric space by taking the induced Euclidean metric, we see that $g$ has only two discountinuitites and not countably many.

Comment: @AIM_BLB Right!  I've edited the question to account for that :)